# Redis dequeue and enqueue to a different server

Tags: redis

I am writing a script that needs to dequeue items from a live  redis queue and enqueue on a remote server

What is the most efficient way for doing this

I need something like the redis MIGRATE command , but I can not lock the incoming queue at the source.

Comment: Well, do not lock it then. LPOP (plus, maybe, LLEN) is your friend.

Comment: Thats what I am doing LPOP on source and RPUSH on destination .. but that is very slow to what MIGRATE can do .. How can I speed this up

Comment: How big are your keys? Can't you tolerate a few ms of locks?

Comment: These keys are going to be big .. lots of queue items and each item will be large ( around 10kb - 100kb ) I can not lock at all

Comment: Is the idea to have the same structure of key/values on both instances ?

Comment: yes the same structure on both servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using migrate()  command in redis solves this requirement

I now rename the queue and fire migrate. There is no lock period because the migrate happens on a different key